# General linear group of tensor product.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, general-linear-group

Given two noetherian algebras $A$ and $B$ over a field, is there any description of $H_n(GL(A\otimes B))$ in terms of $H_i(GL(A))$ and $H_i(GL(B))$? Let's assume homologies for $A$ and $B$ are trivial, does that imply anything regarding the homologies of their tensor?

Comment: This is rather unclear. What flavor of homology are you asking about?

Comment: @KReiser Group homology, or the homology of the classifying space as a discrete group.